# Use NAudio to get Ulaw samples for RTP

Tags: c#, rtp, naudio

I've been looking over the NAudio examples trying to work out how I can get ulaw samples suitable for packaging up as an RTP payload. I'm attempting to generate the samples from an mp3 file using the code below. Not surprisingly, since I don't really have a clue what I'm doing with NAudio, when I transmit the samples across the network to a softphone all I get is static.

Can anyone provide any direction on how I should be getting 160 bytes (8Khz @ 20ms) ULAW samples from an MP3 file using NAudio?

```
private void GetAudioSamples()
{
    var pcmStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new Mp3FileReader("whitelight.mp3"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
    byte[] sampleBuffer = new byte[160];
    int sampleIndex = 0;
    int bytesRead = pcmStream.Read(buffer, 0, 2);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        var ulawByte = MuLawEncoder.LinearToMuLawSample(BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 0));
        sampleBuffer[sampleIndex++] = ulawByte;

        if (sampleIndex == 160)
        {
            m_rtpChannel.AddSample(sampleBuffer);
            sampleBuffer = new byte[160];
            sampleIndex = 0;
        }

        bytesRead = pcmStream.Read(buffer, 0, 2);
    }

    logger.Debug("Finished adding audio samples.");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the way I eventually got it working. I do lose one of the channels from the mp3, and I guess there's some way to combine the channels as part of a conversion, but that doesn't matter for my situation.

The 160 byte buffer size gives me 20ms ulaw samples which work perfectly with the SIP softphone I'm testing with.

```
var pcmFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
var ulawFormat = WaveFormat.CreateMuLawFormat(8000, 1);

using (WaveFormatConversionStream pcmStm = new WaveFormatConversionStream(pcmFormat, new Mp3FileReader("whitelight.mp3")))
{
    using (WaveFormatConversionStream ulawStm = new WaveFormatConversionStream(ulawFormat, pcmStm))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[160];
        int bytesRead = ulawStm.Read(buffer, 0, 160);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            byte[] sample = new byte[bytesRead];
            Array.Copy(buffer, sample, bytesRead);
            m_rtpChannel.AddSample(sample);

            bytesRead = ulawStm.Read(buffer, 0, 160);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what were you using for RTP in c#?

Comment: @gabssnake I used my own crude RTP implementation https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/tree/master/sipsorcery-core/SIPSorcery.Net/RTP. It doesn't support the full RTP standard but it does support enough for basic audio transmission.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a few pointers. First of all, as long as you are using NAudio 1.5, no need for the additional WaveFormatConversionStream - Mp3FileReader's Read method returns PCM.

However, you will not be getting 8kHz out, so you need to resample it first. WaveFormatConversionStream can do this, although it uses the built-in Windows ACM sample rate conversion, which doesn't seem to filter the incoming audio well, so there could be aliasing artefacts.

Also, you usually read bigger blocks than just two bytes at a time as the MP3 decoder needs to decode frames one at a time (the resampler also will want to deal with bigger block sizes). I would try reading at least 20ms worth of bytes at a time.

Your use of BitConverter.ToInt16 is correct for getting the 16 bit sample value, but bear in mind that an MP3 is likely stereo, with left, right samples. Are you sure your phone expects stereo.

Finally, I recommend making a mu-law WAV file as a first step, using WaveFileWriter. Then you can easily listen to it in Windows Media Player and check that what you are sending to your softphone is what you intended.